# Stop combobox from collapsing when [+] in tree within combobox is clicked - extjs 3

Tags: combobox, extjs, tree

I have implemented tree within combobox using idea from [this thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?27269-2.x-ComboBox-Tree)

but when [+] or arrow on tree is clicked, the combobox collapses

Is there any way to stop this????????

Please help me....Thanks alot.......

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for Pepijn who answered my question. Here is the solution:

you can use the tree beforecollapsenode and beforeexpandnode events to find if they are pressed. See the code below:

```
 tree1.on('click',function(node){
             combo.setValue(node.text);
             nodeAction=0;
             combo.collapse();
           });
tree1.on('beforeexpandnode',function(node,deep,anim){
             nodeAction=1;
            });
tree1.on('beforecollapsenode',function(node,deep,anim){
             nodeAction=1;
            });
combo.on('collapse',function(){
               if(nodeAction==1){
                 this.expand();
                 nodeAction=0;
               }  
             });
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here -- my workaround is to show the tree expanded by default.
Yet that doesn't solve the issue with the arrows...

Basically the combobox sees a "blur" event when clicking on the tree and thus collapses.
But I don't know how to prevent that.

By the way, if someone had a **fully working** "combobox + tree" solution for ExtJS, that would be very helpful.
Because the solution provided on the Sencha forums is quite limited:

- Display and value of the combobox has to be the same (whereas I'd like its value to be the tree's node ID)
- There's no way to "restore" the value/display of the combobox when it's part of a form (e.g. using "form.loadRecord()")

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I tried to track but i think when i click on [+] of tree, it doesn't fire events like beforeBlur, blur, beforeselect, change, select and collapse. Out of these only collapse event was fired.

Regards